# Failed to build project after adding firestore, androidx libs and google-services plugin to the latest (4.1.0)

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to work with firebase (firestore) using the androidx/jetpack libraries (navigation, constrintlayout, etc.). but, when adding the google services plugin in the root build.gradle, and the firebase libraries like auth and firestore in the app module build.gradle, the build fails.

*1) root project build.gradle*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha04'
        classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha07'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*(2) app module project build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.bitbucket.marlonlom.elcorral"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.10'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*(3) root project build.gradle*

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:[16.0.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.4].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.2.3].
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Any help with this?

Best regards,

Comment: try firebase-core 16.0.4

Comment: I didnt think including firebase-core in the app (as it containts the features of the analytics thing) i think i need to document more about this, but, it worked as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for the comments: @peter-haddad and @achraf-amil

After all, I made this for fixing the build.gradle files i mentioned before, in terms of reviewing the versions of the libraries i used:

(1) In root *build.gradle*:

```
...
dependencies{
  ...
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha05'
  ...
  //noinspection GradleDependency
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
  ...
}
```

additionally, i listed the versions of the dependencies here.

```
...
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    /* androidx related dependencies */
    androidx_appcompat_version = '1.0.2'
    androidx_core_ktx_version = '1.0.1'
    androidx_constraintlayout_version = '2.0.0-alpha2'
    androidx_legacy_support_v4_version = '1.0.0'
    android_arch_navigation_fragment_ktx_version = '1.0.0-alpha07'
    android_arch_navigation_ui_ktx_version = '1.0.0-alpha07'
    google_material_version = '1.1.0-alpha01'
    /* firebase dependencies */
    firebase_firestore_version = '17.1.1'
    firebase_auth_version = '16.0.4'
    firebase_storage_version = '16.0.3'
    firebase_core_version = '16.0.4'
    play_services_auth_version = '16.0.1'
    /* other dependencies */
    synnapps_carouselview_version = '0.1.5'
    /* Testing dependencies versions*/
    junit_version = '4.12'
    androidx_test_runner_version = '1.1.0'
    androidx_test_espresso_core_version = '3.1.0'
}
```

(2) In app module *build.gradle*, i applied the versions as variable in the dependencies block:

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$rootProject.kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$rootProject.androidx_core_ktx_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.androidx_constraintlayout_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.android_arch_navigation_fragment_ktx_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.android_arch_navigation_ui_ktx_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.google_material_version"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$rootProject.androidx_legacy_support_v4_version"
    implementation "com.synnapps:carouselview:$rootProject.synnapps_carouselview_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.play_services_auth_version"

    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:$rootProject.firebase_firestore_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$rootProject.firebase_auth_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$rootProject.firebase_storage_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.firebase_core_version"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junit_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$rootProject.androidx_test_runner_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.androidx_test_espresso_core_version"

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the //noinspection GradleDependency text part helped in the check of different versions of the library versus google play library versions.

IDK if this is the recommended way, but it worked (for now).

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, try previous versions.
The latest version that works for me (as of today) is 17.1.0

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-firestore

Comment: i found useful the version 17.1.1 of firebase-firestore lib. thanks :)

Comment: You can also read [the official release notes with all the latest versions for Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)